Trace(Trace A) for A matrix
Is there any known meaning of $$Tr(Tr A)$$
where A is a $n \times $n matrix

Trace is defined as the (scalar) sum of the elements in the main diagonal of a square matrix. Taking the trace of a scalar is meaningless unless you "cheat" and imagine it as a $1\times1$ square matrix. Then the trace is the scalar itself.

@Scene PPL even cheat in mathematics now

For all $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ it holds that
$$\mathsf{tr}\left( \mathsf{tr}\left( A \right) \right) = \mathsf{tr}\left( A \right)$$
The trace operator outputs a scalar and the trace of a scalar is a no-op.

Trace is only defined for square matrices.

Right, thanks. It should read $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

No, you did not.

How about Tr(A /Tr(A))?

Use the property that $\mathsf{tr}(cA) = c\mathsf{tr}(A)$ for any scalar $c$

could you suggest something on "https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/812241/401303"  this too
